# what type of interface we will need that will read the file extension of the uploaded file then call the necessary java file

Tags: file, file-upload, interface, upload

what type of interface we will need that will read the file extension of the uploaded file then call the  necessary java file. For example: If you uploaded "hello.pdf" then it will call the pdf.java(which will clear the metadata). I don't know if this is clear but, let me know if you get what i am saying.

Answer (score 1):

Figuring out the extension is fairly simple, call java.io.File.getName().  This will return the full file name plus the extension.  Use string operations like .lastIndexOf(".") and substring to get the extension.

Now you can define an interface for clearing the metadata:

```
public interface MetaDataEraseable {

        public void clearMetaData();

 }
```

Next Create some implementations:

```
public class PDFMetaDataEraser implements MetaDataEraseable {

 public void clearMetaData() { //... do custom pdf code here }


}


public class JpegMetaDataEraser implements MetaDataEraseable {

 public void clearMetaData() { //... do custom jpeg code here }


}
```

Next you can make a factory that will return the proper instance based on the extension:

public static class MetaDataFactory {

```
public MetaDataEraseable getInstance(String ext) {

    if(ext.equalsIgnoreCase("pdf")) {
       return new PDFMetaDataEraser ();
    } else if(ext.equalsIgnoreCase("jpg")) {
       return new JpegMetaDataEraser ();
    }

 }
```

}

Finally call your code in your application...

```
File uploadedFile = //get the file however you want... web upload, file chooser etc

String extension = //write the logic for getting the extension


MetaDataEraseable mde = MetaDataFactory.getInstance(extension);
mde.clearMetaData();
```

The implementation and interface definition may be different depending on your requirements.  For example you may pass the file as an argumant to the clearMetaData() method.

Also please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern if you are not familiar with this approach.  Google 'factory pattern java' to get Java centric examples.  Googlw 'java get file extension' to help you find code examples for getting the file extension in Java.

Good luck!

Comment: Can you please "Dumb it down"?